# How to insert a coordinate into an LineString at a specific index

Tags: geojson, linestring, turf

I have a `LineString`:

```
[
[
    -122.263923,
    37.87459
],
[
    -122.263942,
    37.874587
],
[
    -122.264151,
    37.874534
],
[
    -122.264231,
    37.874511
],
[
    -122.264285,
    37.874495
],
[
    -122.264356,
    37.874472
],
[
    -122.264441,
    37.874441
],
[
    -122.264589,
    37.874381
],
[
    -122.264681,
    37.874346
],
[
    -122.264747,
    37.874334
],
[
    -122.265209,
    37.874271
],
[
    -122.265329,
    37.874258
],
[
    -122.265382,
    37.874252
],
[
    -122.266071,
    37.874169
],
[
    -122.266145,
    37.87416
],
[
    -122.266291,
    37.87415
]]
```

And I want to add a new coordinate in that line
`[-122.263923, 37.87459]`

I'm not sure how to find the right index.
I can find [the closest Point on the (Multi)LineString](https://turfjs.org/docs/#nearestPointOnLine), but I'm not sure the new coordinate should go before or after this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turf.js method `turf.nearestPointOnLine` returns closest point on line to the given point as feature, where property `index` tells on which line string segment point was found. Segments are numbered starting from 0, this denoting segment from first to second point on line string.

This means that if closest point was found on segment N, point has to be inserted after point with index N in line string coordinates array.

If we take that line string coordinates are stored in `lineCoords` variable and point coordinate is stored in `pointCoords` variable, then code for inserting point could look something like this:

```
var line = turf.lineString(lineCoords);
var point = turf.point(pointCoords);

var nearestPoint = turf.nearestPointOnLine(line, point);
var insertIndex = nearestPoint.properties.index;
lineCoords.splice(insertIndex + 1, 0, pointCoords);
```